# R install_github: how to install pull request?

Tags: r, github, devtools

I would like to use in R  `remotes::install_github()` to install/test a pull request from GitHub, how can I do that? I see that there was a `pull` argument in `install_github()` in [older](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.4.1/topics/install_github) versions, but I cannot find it anymore?

Answer (score 2):

You should now (at least for version  `2.4.2` as of February 2023) use the `ref = remotes::github_pull(x)` argument, where x is the pull request number you will find on github.

In full:

```
remotes::install_github(repo=..., ref = remotes::github_pull(60))
```